# Are there any pitfalls in using move() instead of std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

When using new C++11's `std::move()`, I noted that, thanks to ADL, it's possible to just write `move()`, without the `std::` namespace prefix.

Is using `move()` just fine? Are there any pitfalls? Is it just better to use `std::move()`?

---

Sample compilable code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void print(const char* const descr, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    std::cout << descr << ": ";
    for (const auto& x : v) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;    
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{11, 22, 33};
    std::vector<int> w = move(v);

    print("v", v);
    print("w", w);
}
```

Comment: "`move()` looks cleaner than `std::move()`" on the contrary. Also if your `move()` needs to do anything more than `std::move()` and needs to be found by ADL, your `move()` is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADL will only find things in `std` if the argument types are also in `std`.

If there is another symbol called `move` in another namespace that is being used, then the compiler won't know which you meant. There may not be one now, but future changes may bring one in.

Additionally, always having the `std::` makes it a lot easier for people reading your code later. It makes it clear that it's not a `move` that you've defined yourself or included from another library. Especially useful if they've not heard of the (relatively new) `std::move` before.

Comment: Using ADL is the whole purpose of widening the scope of lookup, which is a desired effect. c.f. the whole `boost::swap` idea. I imagine move has no need to be redefined however, since it has one universal implementation. So much so, that it could even be a keyword. But that's a very special case, and not to take as a one against 'ADL enabling pattern' in general.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely use `std::move`! It will work without `std::` *only* if the type is defined in the `std` namespace (due to ADL). It will *not* work with any other type like integral types or use defined types.

---

Example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
std::vector<int> w = move(w); // will work due to ADL
int i1 = 4;
int i2 = move(i1); // ERROR
struct Foo {};
Foo x{};
Foo y = move(x); // ERROR
```

Comment: @Mr.C64: Wait until you need to use move in a template which can use a `vector` or an `int` as template type. Other than that the same argument applies for user defined types.

Comment: you usually declare `using std::move;` before using ADL. these errors seems phony to me if you respect that proper pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same move function that is defined in utility.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move
But for yes code clarity you can write std::move